Fetch all rows which contain value from comma separated values
I have two mysql tables... Students and Batches
batches table :
id   |    batch_name
1         Monday
2         Tuesday
3         Wednesday
4         Thursday
5         Friday
6         Saturday

students Table :
reg_id    |  batches_selected    |   student_name  
 1             1,3,6                    Mr X
 2             2,4,5,6                  Mr Y

Now...
On Students details page of Mr X, I want to show Batches Selected as Monday, Wednesday, Saturday.
What can be mysql query ?
I tried
       <?php
        $batch_id = $memberdata['batches_selected']; // From students table i.e. 1,3,6
        $idsArray = explode(",", $batch_id);
        $idsQuoted = array_map(function ($id) {
            return "'{$id}'";
        }, $idsArray);
        $idsString = join(", ", $idsQuoted);  
                
        $query = "select * from batches where id in ({$idsString}) order by batch_name asc";
        $result = $database->get_results($query);
       ?>
         
       <ul>
        <?php foreach ($result as $batchdata){
            $batch_name_rcvd = $batchdata['batch_name'];
        ?>
            <li><?php echo $batch_name_rcvd;?> </li>
                    
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>

But it is returning only First / One Record.....

Basically your database is poorly designed. If you ever find yourself creating a comma, or anythig else, separated list in a single column it should tell you to go back and read some basic relational database design book/tutorial.

Your unique_id does nothing and is not needed, the id columns should be unique.

Look up creating a cross reference table, to link any number of batches to a student

@RiggsFolly Thank you for suggestions.. I just tried with using id from batches table and removed unique_id. I am not getting why only one row is getting fetched with foreach / loop (Also edited questions as per changes tried at my end)

you would be better to create a student_has_batches table with 2 columns student_id and batch_id. Now you store 3 columns 1,1 - 1,3 - 1,6 now you have the batches linked to the student in a way you can quite simply query for the results you want

Use FIND_IN_SET() to search for a value in a comma-separated list. But it's best to avoid comma-separated lists in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad
